# Prevent react query from refetching data upon user action when data is not updated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I am using React query on a React app that makes multiple paralell requests. Every time I hit tab to go to another app or page, it removes all the dashboards and shows spinner. It refetches all the data and makes all the requests again even when the keyword in the search bar has not changed and, therefore, it is not useful to make the user wait for another few seconds to be able to see the dashboards.

Comment: Per default, react query always shows stale data if there is any and does background refetches at the same time. So please show some code because it must be something like always showing a spinner when isFetching is true or so

Comment: ```
   ) : isLoading || isFetching ? (
            <BounceLoader size={60} color={'#fdcf85'} css={override} />
          ) : isError ? (
            <span>Error: {error.message}</span>
          ) : (
            <>
              <div className='m-4 p-4 flex w-full overflow-x-auto justify-center  items-center  bg-amethyst border-collapse'>
                <Table columns={tableData} data={formatData(data)} />
              </div>
```
Should I get rid of isFetching and only keep isLoading?

Comment: Well if _you_ unmount all the data and show a loading spinner every time a request is in-flight, which is what `isFetching` is doing, and you don’t want that, then yes, I’d suggest to remove that :)

Answer (score 4):

disabling refetch on focus might help you, but I would remove `isFetching` at all and left only `isLoading`

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
   defaultOptions: {
     queries: {
       refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
     },
   },
 })
```

source: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/window-focus-refetching